# How to remove metadata from a Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio

I have personal Visual Studio projects that I would like to expose to the internet. I'm using BatchPurifier to remove metadata from various files but I doubt it gets whatever Visual Studio does.

Comment: **Close-Voting:** *Unclear what you're asking.*

Comment: things like computer name, registration numbers, original creation date, paths, etc

Answer (score 1):

You only need to "expose" the solution, project and source code files.  These are all plain  text files that do not contain metadata and can be reviewed with a simple text editor.  They do not contain secrets unless you put them in yourself.

If you have resources as well then it is entirely up to whatever program or device created the file, Visual Studio isn't involved.

Poking around github or codeplex is a good way to find out how other programmers publish their projects.

Comment: Microsoft does not even include the serial number of your copy of visual studio? I can't imagine them not putting stuff like that in there.

Comment: To clarify, I don't mean them putting it in the plain text part of a file. I mean putting misc data in the file header of some or all of the files.

Comment: No, Microsoft isn't nearly as evil as you assume.

Comment: I never said anything about Microsoft being evil. There is at least one GUID in the plain text part of my .sln files that is the same across projects. I am able to decompile a .exe back to the exact source. The build will still be there if you don't use the default directory. There is obviously various types of meta data all over a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open the solution and project files in a text editing program such as notepad and remove any metadata you find unnecessary. I doubt you will find a tool to remove exactly what you want, you'll have to do it manually.